# Reasoning over rdf to infer (owl:sameas) links

Tags: sparql, owl, jena, ontology, inference

I have a domain ontology (which has only classes) and a rdf graph annotated with this ontology I want to put owl:sameas links between coreferents entities in my graph .For this aim , i want to use owl axiom owl:haskey defined in my ontology to infer owl:sameas links.I can query my graph from apache fuseki .which reasonner should i use to infer those links on the top of apache fuseki ?

Comment: you'd need an OWL 2 compliant reasoner that works with Apache Jena. The only one I'm aware of Pellet resp. it's fork Openllet for Jena 4.x

Comment: @UninformedUser how can i use pellet with fuseki